# checking adjacent elements of an element in an array of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

So, i have a char table that looks like

```
[[.,*,.,.,*]
[*,.,.,.,.]
[.,.,.,*,*]]
```

I want to turn every "." into a number, that shows how many * are in the adjacent fields. Basically a simple minesweeper. 
Is there an elegant way to check every adjacent field of each element?
Because what i have in mind is a lot of nested for cycles and if statements, but im sure there is a nicer way to do it?

Edit: The expected result should be something like :

```
[[3,*,2,.]
 [*,*,2,.]]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried. There is no really elegant way, you will have to check for the bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most elegant way i can think of is this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[] a = {'.', '.', '*', '.', '*'};
    char[] b = {'.', '*', '*', '.', '*'};
    char[] c = {'.', '.', '*', '.', '*'};
    char[] d = {'.', '*', '*', '.', '*'};
    char[] e = {'*', '.', '*', '.', '*'};
    char[][] ae = {a, b, c, d, e};

    char[][] numberArray = new char[5][5];


    for (int i = 0; i < ae.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ae[i].length;  j++) {
            numberArray[i][j] = checkAdjacentField(i, j, ae);
        }
    }
    StringBuilder matrix = new StringBuilder();

    for (char[] aNumberArray : numberArray) {
        StringBuilder bld = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (char character : aNumberArray) {
            bld.append(character).append(",");
        }
        bld.deleteCharAt(bld.length() - 1);
        bld.append("}");
        matrix.append(bld.toString()).append("\n");
    }
    System.out.println(matrix.toString());
}

private static char checkAdjacentField(int i, int j, char[][] ae) {
    int count = 0;
    if (j <= ae[i].length - 2) { // to the right
        count += ae[i][j + 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (j <= ae[i].length - 2 && i <= ae.length -2) { // move to top right
        count += ae[i + 1][j + 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (j <= ae[i].length - 2 && i > 0) { // move to bottom right
        count += ae[i - 1][j + 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (j > 0) { // to the left
        count += ae[i][j - 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (j > 0 && i <= ae.length -2) { // to top left
        count += ae[i + 1][j - 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (j > 0 && i > 0) { // to bottom left
        count += ae[i - 1][j - 1] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (i <= ae.length -2) { // move to top
        count += ae[i +1][j] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    if (i > 0) { // move top bottom
        count += ae[i - 1][j] == '*' ? 1 : 0;
    }
    System.out.printf("field %s, %s has %s Adjacent fields with a * \n", i, j , count);
    String stringValue = String.valueOf(count);
    return stringValue.charAt(0);
}
```

If you have questions about this example i would like to hear it.

Next time, try to provide an example of what you've all ready tried before.

Comment: I want my result to look like  [[3,*,.]
                                              [*,*,.]
Your solution, didnt count the diagonal * for some reason? Also, if i wanted the checkAdjacent method to replace '.'s to numbers instead of just printig them, what should i modify on the method? Apart from making it return a char[][]

edit: Ah sry, i dont know how to format commets, ill edit the question with the expected outcome

Comment: I did not know you wanted to include diagonal checks, this would result in four more if checks which you can base on the previous 4. I would not return a char[][] but just the number of the field

Comment: I updated the answer. It is not the cleanest code, but i think this will do for now